# How to get currently logged user in class-based view?

Tags: python, django

I have class-based view:

```
class AddView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'
```

MyModel:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I'd like to automatically set currently logged user into field 'user' whenever new record is added. How can I do that ?

Comment: This is specifically documented: [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the currently logged in user through request. When a URL is called and the requested passed into the view just call:

```
class AddView(CreateView)         
    def myView(request):    
        user = request.user
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user (Thanks Daniel)